# Copying content of file into another file in Python

Tags: python, file

All I am trying to do is copy the contents of one file, called 'example.txt' and put them into the output file.  Here is what I have but nothing happens when I run it.  I am probably missing something obvious but can't figure out what.

```
def fcopy(fileName1,fileName2):
    fileIn=open(fileName1, 'r')
    fileOut=open(fileName2, 'w')
    for word in fileIn.readlines():
        fileOut.write(word)
    fileIn.close()
    fileOut.close()
```

This is how I call it:

```
fcopy('example.txt','output.txt')
open('output.txt')
```

Comment: if nothing happens it means that `open` succeeded: it has worked!

Comment: Did it copy the content of example to output ?

Comment: `open('output.txt')` does not automatically print the contents of the file to the console, neither does it open an editor to view the contents.

Comment: Your program works fine. Just tested it.
As @ChristianKönig said, open doesn't display the content of the file to you. If you want to do that then print each line in `out.txt`.

Comment: Almost there. If you want to see the contents use `.readlines()`. Example: `print(''.join(open('output.txt').readlines()))`

Comment: If you dont want to write your own function then there are already available modules in python, which you can use.

Comment: that function above does not copy the file but the file _lines_. It means that CR/LF or LF line terminations may be altered in the copy.

Comment: @Zroq: `print(open("output.txt").read())` is even simpler